# ¿Como llamar a un servicio zeep python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, soap, zeep

Estoy intentando conectarme a un servicio SOAP con la librería Zeep.

Tengo una función que maqueta los datos y realiza la llamada:

```
def cotizacionGuia(self,valor_declarado):
    wsdl = 'https://redservipruebas.almalogix.com/distribucion/webservices/ws_cotizadorEnvios.php?wsdl'
    client = zeep.Client(wsdl=wsdl,plugins=[MyLoggingPlugin()])
    client.set_ns_prefix('ws', '/distribucion/webservices/ws_cotizadorEnvios.php')
    client.set_ns_prefix('xsi',"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
    client.set_ns_prefix('soapenv',"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
    client.set_ns_prefix('soapenc','http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/')
    factory = client.type_factory('ws')
```

Al utilizar el comando `python -mzeep https://redservipruebas.almalogix.com/distribucion/webservices/ws_cotizadorEnvios.php?wsdl` he descubierto que el servicio se llama `WebServiceCotizadorEnvios.ws_cotizarEnvio`.

Mi problema es que al tener este nombre no soy capaz de realizar la llamada al servicio usando `client.service.WebServiceCotizadorEnvios.ws_cotizarEnvio()`.

¿Hay alguna forma de renombrar el nombre del servicio?

He descubierto que escribiendo `client.service._binding.port_type.operations` obtengo un dict donde se encuentra el nombre del servicio como clave y el objeto como valor, entonces he pensado que si puedo modificar la clave, podría realizar la llamada.

---

He conseguido solucionar el problema realizando el siguiente cambio:

Hay dos formas para llamar a las funciones de `service`, una de ellas es la que vengo usando hasta ahora `client.service.llamada()` y la otra es `client.service['llamada'](parametros)`. De esta segunda forma da igual el nombre que tenga la función que podremos realizar la llamada.

Comment: Normalmente harías  `client=zeep.Client(wsdl=blabla/WebServiceCotizadorEnvios.wsdl)` y luego `client.service.ws_cotizarEnvio()`.

Comment: pero es que el servicio se llama `WebServiceCotizadorEnvios.ws_cotizarEnvio` y no `ws_cotizarEnvio()` y si busco el servicio por uno de los dos nombres no existe y si pongo el nombre completo solo me coge hasta el punto y me dice que no sirve.

Comment: Pero fíjate que en el ejemplo que puse antes al conectar le pasas el parámetro `wsdl` con el nombre del servicio y luego al utilizar `client.service` le paso el método (o como se llame).

Comment: no funciona, me sigue dando el mismo error

Comment: Hola, ¿puedes mostrar la parte de tu código en la que intentas llamar al sevicio? Me parece que tu código está incompleto

Comment: explico debajo del código como intento realizar la llamada, no lo he añadido al bloque del código porque no funcionaba.

Comment: Hay dos formas para llamar a las funciones de service , una de ellas es la que vengo usando hasta ahora client. service. llamada() y la otra es client. service['llamada'](parametros) .

Comment: Esta solución ya la dio @FDelgado anteriormente en su propia pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

En Zeep, no es posible renombrar directamente el nombre del servicio definido en el WSDL. El nombre del servicio es parte de la especificación del WSDL y está asociado con las funciones y operaciones específicas definidas en él.

Si necesitas utilizar un nombre diferente para el servicio SOAP en tu código, puedes considerar la opción de crear una clase personalizada que actúe como un proxy para el servicio real. Esta clase personalizada puede tener un nombre diferente y puede encapsular la lógica de llamada al servicio utilizando el nombre original del servicio.

Aquí hay un ejemplo de cómo podrías implementar esto:

```
import zeep

class MyCustomService:
    def __init__(self, wsdl_url):
        self.client = zeep.Client(wsdl=wsdl_url)
def myCustomFunction(self, params):
    return 

self.client.service.WebServiceCotizadorEnvios.ws_cotizarEnvio(params)

wsdl_url = 'https://redservipruebas.almalogix.com/distribucion/webservices/ws_cotizadorEnvios.php?wsdl'
custom_service = MyCustomService(wsdl_url)
response = custom_service.myCustomFunction(params)
```